# how to read xml from remote url in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i am working in a project in that i want to read some data from the remote url can any one help me how to do this function

Answer (score 7):

You can use a WebRequest to retrieve the XML from the remote site; then you can parse the contents into an XmlDocument object.

```
' Create a WebRequest to the remote site
Dim request As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.domain.com/fetch.xml")

' NB! Use the following line ONLY if the website is protected
request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")

' Call the remote site, and parse the data in a response object
Dim response As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()

' Check if the response is OK (status code 200)
If response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then

    ' Parse the contents from the response to a stream object
    Dim stream As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    ' Create a reader for the stream object
    Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(stream)
    ' Read from the stream object using the reader, put the contents in a string
    Dim contents As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    ' Create a new, empty XML document
    Dim document As New System.Xml.XmlDocument()

    ' Load the contents into the XML document
    document.LoadXml(contents)

    ' Now you have a XmlDocument object that contains the XML from the remote site, you can
    ' use the objects and methods in the System.Xml namespace to read the document

Else
    ' If the call to the remote site fails, you'll have to handle this. There can be many reasons, ie. the 
    ' remote site does not respond (code 404) or your username and password were incorrect (code 401)
    '
    ' See the codes in the System.Net.HttpStatusCode enumerator 

    Throw New Exception("Could not retrieve document from the URL, response code: " & response.StatusCode)

End If
```

Comment: 'GetResponse' is not a member of 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'.

Comment: @ScottBeeson In which programming language? For .NET, System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() has been around since version 1.1, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: vb.net 4.5, Visual Studio 2012

Comment: @ScottBeeson See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx

Comment: I believe you, I'm just telling you what the IDE is telling me :)

Comment: @ScottBeeson OK, write me a PM if you cope with a problem at this moment and I'll try to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Along with what @Jon Skeet said there's also the built-in [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx):

```
    Dim MyData As String
    Try
        Using WC As New System.Net.WebClient()
            MyData = WC.DownloadString("http://www.example.com/text.xml")
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        'Error downloading
    End Try
```

Comment: FYI [Microsoft no longer recommends using `WebClient` for new development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-6.0#remarks) and suggests using [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [`XDocument.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx) or [`XmlDocument.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/875kz807.aspx)?

If those don't do what you want, please give more details.

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/992109/Parsing-Reading-XML-from-URL-in-VB-NET

There are some useful examples provided with it. Hope this helps...