# How to use request and respond with xml and VB.net?

Tags: xml, vb.net, winforms, wsdl, request

I was asked to send a request to a server to register online a transaction for a point gathering system. I don know much about this request-respond procedure.

They told me that the request should be like this:

```
request( 
p1 - loginInfo:UN|PASS|MP1
p2 - XMLTransactionInfo (below)
p3 - returnPointBalance:1
)

<transaction>
  <partnernum>000001</partnernum>
  <trxndate>2012-10->12T07:18:27</trxndate>
  <cardnum>1234567891234567</cardnum>
  <trxnamount>5.4</trxnamount>
  <trxnpoints>729</trxnpoints>
  <posnum>000-001</posnum>
  <contactidnum></contactidnum>
  <contactphone>357</contactphone>
  <trxnseqnum>12345612345612</trxnseqnum>
</transaction>
```

And the response should be like this:

```
response(    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<transactionresponse xmlns="C:\path\Sth.ear\Sth.war/xmlschema/TransactionResponse.rng">
  <sequencenum>123123121312</sequencenum> 
  <errorcode>0</errorcode> 
  <errormessage></errormessage> 
  <trxnnum>6399575</trxnnum> 
  <balancebefore>1942</balancebefore> 
  <balanceafter>1213</balanceafter> 
  <mpcontrib>729</mpcontrib> 
  <partnercontrib>0</partnercontrib> 
</transactionresponse>
)
```

They also told me: "You can get the WSDL with this URL: url1..." and "The WS endpoint is: url2..."

So far i've managed to do the following:

```
Dim request As WebRequest = Nothing

  'Create a request for the URL.
  request =WebRequest.Create("URL1")

  'set the credentials.
  Dim credentials As NetworkCredential
  loginUser = "username"
  loginPass = "pass"
  credentials = New NetworkCredential(loginUser, loginPass, "MP1")
  request.Credentials = credentials

  'create the transaction xml
  request.ContentType = "text/xml"
  Dim transaction As XmlElement
  transaction = xml2.CreateElement("transaction")
  xml2.AppendChild(transaction)

  Dim partnernum As XmlElement
  partnernum = xml2.CreateElement("partnernum")
  partnernum.InnerText = "00001"
  transaction.AppendChild(partnernum)

  'and so on until i create the exact same xml as above...
```

Then I print the XML file to the console for a visual check and then ask for response

```
  'print to console
  xml2.Save(Console.Out)
  Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
  Console.WriteLine(response.ToString())
  'write the response to a textbox
  responseText.Text = response.Headers.ToString()
```

The result of the response in the textbox is

```
Content-Language: el-GR
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml
Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2012 18:52:33
GMT Server: WebSphere Application Server/6.0
```

Firstly which one of the 2 urls that they gave me I should I use?

Secondly how can I create the request that they told me in order to get the response I am suppose to get?

Is there any step by step guide for that?

I am using VB.net,  WinForms.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you have a URL for a WSDL, add a "Web Reference" in Visual Studio using that URL and it will generate the code you need to access the webservice.

Comment: The XML you posted is invalid. Please post the real XML. Then, select it in the editor and press CTRL-K (the icon with the curly brackets).

Comment: KBoek's answer on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757731/how-to-read-xml-from-remote-url-in-vb-net
might steer you in the right direction - couldn't really tell if it applies (might answer your 1st and 2nd questions). Additionally, I found this from a bit more digging: http://robz.homedns.org:8080/blog/archive/2005/02/25/387.aspx

Comment: Please add the printout of your request which you said you printout before sending the request.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to the WSDL url in Visual Studio.